# Can you embed the feed from a Facebook Workplace in an iframe?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-workplace

My client has an intranet, on which they wish for a news-feed from their Facebook Workplace-account. They refer to an ordinary Facebook iframe-embed from an open page, and basically want that.

After doing some research I've strenghtened my belief that this can't be done, since the feed isn't public. But before I tell my client that we have to do it through the API and implement the design ourselves, I though't I'd just throw the question out there. So, can anyone confirm or refute that this is impossible?

Thanks :)

Comment: Just in case anyone stumbles upon this, I never found a way to do it in an iframe. I just implemented my own design based on the raw data from the API.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is the best and safest one for sure.  And probably the only one supported by Facebook (except for the feed design part, which is up to you).

---

But I can imagine an alternative solution: you can get the feed rendered content via Workplace Web Page itself.  Just access the user feed via a headless web browser and download the rendered page.  You can do it with Selenium+PhantomJS.

Of course I consider this solution a hack, not supported by Facebook, and it will probably break every time Facebook changes its UI.  Particularly, I really would not waste any efforts doing it, but it can be done (and maybe it is easier than mimicking Facebook's feed design).